# Syntax error (missing operator) in MS-Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

The following query is giving me the `"(missing operator)"` syntax error. The desired output is a combination of data from tables `[dbo_tbl*]` and views `[vw_*]`. All of the keys I've used exist. Any ideas?

```
SELECT dbo_tbl_BOD.fpartno AS PartNumber,
      dbo_tbl_BOD.frev AS RevisionIssue,
      vw_DOCSwType.DocID,
      vw_DRHRelfilter.Rev,
      vw_DOCSwType.DocTypeDesc,
      vw_DOCSwType.DocDesc,
      vw_DOCSwType.DwgNoLegacy,
      vw_DOCSwType.FileLocationOld,
      vw_DRHRelfilter.DateCreated,
      vw_DOCSwType.CreatedBy,
      vw_DRHRelfilter.Rel,
      vw_DRHRelfilter.RelLink
FROM dbo_tbl_BOD
LEFT JOIN vw_DRHRelfilter
      ON ((dbo_tbl_BOD.DocID=vw_DRHRelfilter.DocID)
     AND (dbo_tbl_BOD.frev=vw_DRHRelfilter.Rev))
 LEFT JOIN vw_DOCSwType
      ON (dbo_tbl_BOD.DocID=vw_DOCSwType.DocID)
ORDER BY PartNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit bluefeet. Newbie here, is there information on formatting for entry on this site somewhere? My formatting was stripped from my original text posting.

Comment: To format text as code, select the text then press the code sample button which looks like "{}".  You can also select the text then press `Ctrl+k`. More information about editing options here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Access, each join needs parentheses, say:

```
SELECT dbo_tbl_BOD.fpartno AS PartNumber,
dbo_tbl_BOD.frev AS RevisionIssue,
vw_DOCSwType.DocID,
vw_DRHRelfilter.Rev,
vw_DOCSwType.DocTypeDesc,
vw_DOCSwType.DocDesc,
vw_DOCSwType.DwgNoLegacy,
vw_DOCSwType.FileLocationOld,
vw_DRHRelfilter.DateCreated,
vw_DOCSwType.CreatedBy,
vw_DRHRelfilter.Rel,
vw_DRHRelfilter.RelLink
FROM (dbo_tbl_BOD
LEFT JOIN vw_DRHRelfilter
ON dbo_tbl_BOD.DocID=vw_DRHRelfilter.DocID
AND dbo_tbl_BOD.frev=vw_DRHRelfilter.Rev)
LEFT JOIN
vw_DOCSwType
ON dbo_tbl_BOD.DocID=vw_DOCSwType.DocID
ORDER BY PartNumber;
```

If you have a copy of MS Access, you can easily see the required parentheses by using the query design window to build your joins.

You can use VBA to check field types, for example:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("query1")
For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Debug.Print fld.SourceField, fld.SourceTable, _
        DLookup("SQLName", "DataTypeEnum", "DataValue=" & fld.Type)
Next
```

The table DataTypeEnum contains text descriptions for the numeric values returned by fld.type.

```
DataValue  SQLName
1   Boolean
2   Byte
3   Integer
4   Long
5   Currency
6   Single
7   Double
8   Date
9   Binary
10  Text
11  LongBinary
12  Memo
15  GUID
16  BigInt
17  VarBinary
18  Char
19  Numeric
20  Decimal
21  Float
22  Time
23  TimeStamp
```

Comment: Thanks @Remou. Now I'm getting a type mismatch error when executing the query.

Comment: This is likely to be due to one of the matches being of different type, for example matching a text type to a numeric type field (column), for `example dbo_tbl_BOD.frev=vw_DRHRelfilter.Rev`

Comment: I can easily see the datatype in my Access tables, but how do I determine the datatype returned in views?

Comment: I do not get your point. Do you not know your data types? Are you not working within Access?

Comment: Sorry for all the newbie questions. Working in Access. Is there a way to display the data type returned in a view / query? Otherwise I need to resolve back through the queries to the originating table to match up data type.